# where do we have userPermission " AllowUniversalSearch"

Tags: permissions, profile

While exporting the metadata of SystemAdminstrator Profile I am getting a user permission " AllowUniversalSearch" but not able to figure out from where can we set this permission as it is not visible on System Admin profile.
I searched over net about this permission but could find nothing related to this

Answer (score 2):

You would create a `permission set` to enable it. See the [Security Workbook - Create Permission Sets](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/workbook_security/Content/func_access_3.htm)  and [Permission Set Best Practice: You Should Try THIS Out at Home](http://blogs.salesforce.com/product/2012/01/permission-set-best-practice-you-should-try-this-out-at-home.html).

Answer (score 0):

The API name is "AllowUniversalSearch" and the Lable is "Knowledge One"

http://www.fishofprey.com/2020/10/mappings-between-salesforce-permission.html