# Where can I find a mapping between a profile setting label and the underlying XML tag for a profile?

Tags: profile, permission-sets, xml, field-mapping

I am trying to audit a profile.  I have a sheet with the labels in the profile, and I have the profile XML.  But there is no simple concordance between something like this:

```
<userPermissions>
  <enabled>true</enabled>
  <name>AllowUniversalSearch</name>
</userPermissions>
```

and this

[image]

so, how do I figure out where this "AllowUniversalSearch" setting is?  I have checked the docs and did a search on Google, and here, but have not found it anywhere.

Does someone have a way of getting this information easily, without checking a box and exporting the profile?

Thanks,

Scott

Answer (score 0):

Using a search for the string `userpermissions` on the help site: https://help.salesforce.com/search#q=userpermissions&f:@objecttype=%5BHelpDocs%5D&f:@sflanguage=%5Ben_US%5D&firstQueryMeta=%5Bobject%20Object%5D

and filtering by `documentation` returns the following:

> To view permissions and their descriptions, from Setup, enter Permission Sets in the Quick Find box, then select Permission Sets, then select or create a permission set. Then from the Permission Set Overview page, click App Permissions or System Permissions.

In addition, you can also find more information on `allowuniversalsearch` by searching:

1. Here: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/search?q=allowuniversalsearch
2. Github: https://github.com/search?q=allowuniversalsearch&type=Issues

**References**

- [Salesforce Field Reference Guide (pdf)](https://resources.docs.salesforce.com/sfdc/pdf/salesforce_field_names_reference.pdf)
- [User Permissions](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=admin_userperms.htm&type=5)
- [Profiles and Permission Sets deployment in Salesforce](https://medium.com/@medben/profiles-permission-sets-deployment-in-salesforce-d53bd3a4771a)
- [where do we have userPermission " AllowUniversalSearch"](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/46013/where-do-we-have-userpermission-allowuniversalsearch)

Answer (score 0):

The API name is "AllowUniversalSearch" and the Lable is "Knowledge One"

http://www.fishofprey.com/2020/10/mappings-between-salesforce-permission.html